# Is $d\theta$ a vector and does the equation $d\vec{s}=d\theta \times \vec{r}$ make sense?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, work, torque

I was reading about [torque on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque) and I found this passage (in the section "Relationship between torque, power, and energy")

> The work done by a variable force acting over a finite linear
> displacement $s$ is given by integrating the force with respect to an
> elemental linear displacement $d\vec{s}$
>
> $$W=\int_{s_1}^{s_2} \vec{F} \cdot \vec{ds}$$

Note that I inserted the vector arrows above, though in the Wikipedia article the variables are in bold (though it isn't very clear always whether there is a bold font or not so I may make a mistake in transcribing). In particular, I am not sure if $d\theta$ is a vector or not.

> However, the infinitesimal linear displacement $d\vec{s}$ is related
> to a corresponding angular displacement $d\theta$ and the radius
> vector $\vec{r}$ as
> $$d\vec{s}=d\theta \times \vec{r}$$

Is the last equation correct? It seems like $d\theta$ is a scalar and $\vec{r}$ is a vector. My question is if I read the passage correctly, and if so, if it is correct as written.

Later in the passage, it seems like $d\theta$ is in fact a vector, because the $d\vec{s}$ expression is substituted into the work equation

$$W=\int_{s_1}^{s_2} \vec{F}\cdot d\theta \times \vec{r}$$

I am confused because usually I see arc length being $ds=rd\theta$.

Answer (score 3):

The key is that $\text d\boldsymbol\theta$ is a *differential*, and thus is an infinitesimal quantity. This can be seen by doing the simple "experiment" below. While this answer is not mathematically rigorous, I think it shows how we get a vector from angular displacements. This experiment is from a "discussion question" exercise from Sears & Zemansky's "University Physics with Modern Physics" 13th edition:

> Although angular velocity and angular acceleration can be treated as vectors, the angular displacement $\theta$, despite having a magnitude and direction, cannot. This is is because $\theta$ does not follow the commutative law of vector addition.
>
> Prove this to yourself in the following way: Lay your physics textbook flat on the desk in front of you with the cover side up so that you can read the writing on it. Rotate it through $90^\circ$ about a horizontal axis so that farthest edge comes toward you. Call this angular displacement $\theta_1$. Then rotate by $90^\circ$ about a vertical axis so that the left edge comes toward you. Call this angular displacement $\theta_2$. The spine of the book should now face you, with the writing oriented so that you can read it.
>
> Now start over again but carry out the two rotations in the reverse order. Do you get a different result? That is, does $\theta_1+\theta_2$ equal $\theta_2+\theta_1$?
>
> Now repeat this experiment but this time with an angle of $1^\circ$ rather than $90^\circ$. Do you think that the infinitesimal displacement $\text d\boldsymbol\theta$ obeys the commutative law of addition and hence qualifies as a vector? If so, how is the direction of $\text d\boldsymbol\theta$ related to the direction of $\boldsymbol
> \omega$?

The infinitesimal angular displacement can be treated as a vector just fine, even if "larger" displacements cannot be.

Answer (score 2):

In the wikipedia's article, it is written $d\boldsymbol \theta \times \mathbf r$, the cross product of a (pseudo)vector and a vector. As the direction of the pseudovector is perpendicular to the plane of movement, the resultant vector is tangent to the trajectory.

Answer (score 1):

Lets start with this equation

$$\vec v=\vec\omega\times \vec r\tag 1$$

with :
$$\vec v=v\,\vec e_v=\frac{ds}{dt}\,\vec e_v$$

and
$$\vec\omega=\omega\,\vec e_\omega=\frac{d\theta}{dt}\,\vec e_\omega$$

you obtain that

$$ds\,\vec e_v=d\theta\,\vec e_\omega\times \vec r$$

hence

$$\vec{ds}=ds\,\vec e_v\quad,\vec{d\theta}=d\theta\,\vec e_\omega\\
\text{so that}\\
\vec{ds}=\vec{d\theta}\times\vec{r}$$

so

$$\vec F\cdot\vec{ds}\mapsto \vec F\cdot(\vec{d\theta}\times\vec{r})=\vec F\cdot\left(d\theta\,\vec e_\omega\times \vec r\right)=\vec F\cdot\left(\vec e_\omega\times \vec r\right)\,d\theta$$
this make sense